# Exporting custom properties to PDF with org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Org-mode in Emacs and have an org document with some tasks. For some tasks, I added a custom property called `PEOPLE`, which lists the people involved in performing this task.

When I export this document to HTML or pdf, only properties which are "Special Properties" like `DEADLINE` or `SCHEDULE` are exported to HTML or pdf and appear in the exported document. I am not able to see the `PEOPLE` property when I export the document.

Is there a way to add custom properties to the "Special Properties" list of Org mode?

Answer (score 6):

Look into using the "d:" field in the options list (http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-options.html#Export-options) or the :drawers option for html publishing (http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html#Publishing-options). Without knowing more detail about how you are doing the exporting, that's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: I was using the normal export functions
C-c C-e h for HTML export 
C-c C-e d for pdf export and the d: option in the header for the org mode document works and it adds the properties or stuff that are added as Drawers to the pdf or the html. 

Thanks for the answer!
Shyam

Comment: @Jin: If it works, you probably want to *accept* the answer (tick on the side).

Comment: this solutions does not work for org-mode v 8.2.10 (BTW the link for the export options is broken). I've been trying to export properties without success, indeed I've found this page http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html where you can read "You can select the name of the drawers which should be exported with org-export-with-drawers. In that case, drawer contents will appear in export output. *Property drawers* are not affected by this variable and *are never exported*." :(

Answer (score 2):

By now what I'm doing is using this http://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html to add a table (with the desired properties) at the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

It might only work with 8.3, but you can use `#+OPTIONS: prop:t` or put the list of properties you want to include.

From [12.3 Export settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html):

> `prop`:
>   Toggle inclusion of property drawers, or list properties to include (`org-export-with-properties`).